# Склонение слова "фейхоа"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Думаю, все знают такой тропический плод, как фейхоа. Но только вот никто не может толком сказать, как склоняется его название. Я как-то пытался что-то объяснить, но уперся в то, что любая форма, образованная от слова "фейхоа", звучит, мягко говоря, малоприлично))) Но не образовывать никакие формы тоже как-то неудобно. Нужно хотя бы множественное число. Или например, какое из них будет варенье?))) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки склоняется фейхоа.

[image]

Comment: Последние две болезни - прелесть!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак не склоняется. Неизменяемое слово. Откройте словарь, их же навалом в сети.

Comment: Этот форум существует для того, чтобы на вопросы давали ответы, а не отсылали к словарям. Этак Вы пользователей распугаете.  
Администрация

Comment: Ну ответ-то дан. Понятный и правильный. А словари (отсылка к ним) - это для особо упрямых.

Answer (score 2):

ФЕЙХОА, неизм.; ж. [исп. Feijoa]
1.
Вечнозелёный кустарник сем. миртовых. Ф. выращивают в Грузии и в Крыму. Ф. - культура сравнительно молодая и пока малораспространённая в нашей стране.
2.
Плод этого растения тёмно-зелёного цвета с запахом земляники и ананаса. Ф. содержит много йода и применяется при лечении склероза.(Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов).
Правильно: ***Варенье из фейхоа.***

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что автор очень хотел запостить картинку, поэтому и вопрос придумал. 
А суть-то в другом. Это тонкий маркетинговый ход. Продавцы из солнечных республик обожают коверкать русские слова именно на ценниках. Они хорошо знают, что для привлечения покупателя все средства хороши.

> > > Или например, какое из них будет варенье?)))

А вот никакое. Только варенье из фейхоа. Бывают такие случаи неполной парадигмы у иностранных слов. Вот навскидку: бра, боа, дао, кашне, иваси... "Ивасевая" еще можно при желании изобрести, но не нормативно.  С остальными уже совсем никак.

И специальной формы множественного нет. "Красивые фейхоа", если уж очень надо. Но лучше все равно: "Красивые **плоды** фейхоа".

Comment: Да картинка-то не топик-стартера.

Comment: Да да. Не его. Но она ему очень понравилась. Я так понимаю.